# Not able to move my inline JavaScript to an external file

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I finished developing and testing my HTML intake form and it is working nicely with ajax, json, and validation, and mailing. To finalize the form for production, I attempted to move the JavaScript from the HTML page to an external file and provide a link to the file in the HTML page. The js file is called formjs.js, and the link to it was placed at the bottom of the HTML page as `<script src="../js/formjs.js"></script>`.

The way I moved the JavaScript is cutting the scripts and pasting to the new js page and same the page and linked to it in the HTML page as mentioned above.

Upon doing so, I received tons of error messages on the js page because many of the functions are looking for information that exists on the HTML and had no idea how to get it. For example, a document. For example, this following script:

```
var Server_response_value_failure = document.getElementById("server_response_value_failure");
```

gets the following error:this variable is assigned and value but was never used.

Another example:

`end of function`};

at the end of each function get the error message that unnecessary semicolon.

I am not sure how to link the formjs.js file back to the HTML. Otherwise, the form works perfectly fine if I leave the script on the HTML page.

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct? `../` in your path could be right, but there is not usually a reason to do so. What is the path to your html file and your JS file?

Comment: I suggest putting together a JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net), to tell whether the problem is your code, or your project structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its fine, its just eslint that gives these warnings. for example, it will complain if you declare a variable and assign a value but you dont use the variable later on.

or if you call a function that you declare "later down" in the file.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I just tested the form with all these notices and warning showing in the formjs.js file in the editor. And, the form worked beautifully as designed. Thank you very much for pointing this out. I was going crazy with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help, but sometimes you want to put the entire body of your javascript file in round parenthesis like this

```
(function(...) {
    ...
})();
```

in the end, you put another round parenthesis. This basically acts like `$.ready()` in jQuery.
I don't know if this will help you. You might want to rewrite your code.